# How to get added record without committing the TransactionScope in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, mstest, transactionscope

I have a integration test project

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _scope = new TransactionScope();
        _context.Vendor.Add(new Vendor()
        {
            Name = "VENDOR123"
        });
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void CleanUp()
    {
        _scope.Dispose();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task GetVendor()
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("vendors");
        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); //VENDOR123 won't be available here unless I do _scope.Complete();
        Assert.IsNotNull(response);
    }
```

Is there any way to get the added records (VENDOR123) within my TestMethod? What I'm trying to do is I will seed certain records before running the test, then after the test is finished, I will rollback the scope so that my DB won't be filled with garbage records.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the same DbContext instance, or the same SQL Connection to see the uncommitted data.